# Using ListConverter with forceSelection=false

Tags: jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I am using `<p:autocomplete>` tags and omnifaces converters in order to let  the user choose addresses from a list of given addresses in the system. Below is the sample .xhtml code for two address fields:

```
   <p:autoComplete id="name" completeMethod="#{viewBean.autocompleteName}" var="_address"
        value="#{viewBean.draft.address}" itemValue="#{_address}"
        itemLabel="#{_address.name}">
        <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{viewBean.addresses}" />
         <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{_address.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{_address.street}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{viewBean.onAddressSelected}" update="addressPanel" />
    </p:autoComplete>

    <p:autoComplete id="street" completeMethod="#{viewBean.autocompleteStreet}" var="_address"
        value="#{viewBean.draft.address}" itemValue="#{_address}"
        itemLabel="#{_address.street}">
        <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{viewBean.addresses}" />
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{_address.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <h:outputText value="#{_address.street}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{viewBean.onAddressSelected}" update="addressPanel" />
    </p:autoComplete>
```

Upon selection, the other fields (for the other address attributes) are filled automatically. So far, that works fine.

Here comes the problem:
I would like to allow input that is different from any exising item in the list of options (`forceSelection="false"`). Let's say the user choses an existing address but then changes the name of the street and saves it.

Currently, using the ListConverter, this change is simply ignored and the  object stays the same.

The behaviour I want is that the business object (`viewBean.draft.address`) is modified and saved. In other words, the new object is not anymore a member of the list of options that I provided to the converter.

Is there a way to realize this behaviour but still using the benefits of the `omnifaces.ListConverter`? Or do I have to write my own converter completely from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to just add the query to the list.

```
public List<Address> autocompleteStreet(String query) {
   addresses = addressService.listByStreet(query);
   addresses.add(0, new Address(query)); // <-- Just add query to list.
   return addresses;
}
```

---

**Update** based on comments, PF appears to be buggy when dealing with `forceSelection="false"` and converted item values. Your best bet is to extend OmniFaces `ListConverter` as below and then use it instead.

```
@FacesConverter("addressListConverter")
public class AddressListConverter extends ListConverter {

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        return ((Address) value).getStreet();
    }

}
```

Comment: So I assume you meant `List<Address>` as the return type instead of `List<Street>` and instead of  
`addresses.add(0, new Address(query));` something like:  
`Address tmpAddress = new Address(draft.getAddress()); // the current address  
tmpAddress.setStreet(query);  
addresses.add(0, tmpAddress);`  
In order to have all the other fields of the address keep their values.

Comment: It never occurred to me that the list that is given to the converter can also be altered dynamically. 
This approach seems to work, the only drawback I see is that it is unintuitive for the user to be forced to use the autocomplete suggestions and not being able just to enter something in the textfields that can then be used. Anyway, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Ah, Street was just a typo, I was distracted halfway writing the answer and then I looked back to your question. It has been fixed. As to the drawback, you could e.g. optionally hide the item with CSS.

Comment: But then how can I make sure the "selection" of that item is actually done? I just did a test and even though I set `forceSelection=true` it is possible to just enter some new value and then click somewhere else on the page (not on the suggestion). The suggestion popup goes away and the value is correctly set the text field, but then when I hit "Save" and the form is submitted the address actually evaluates to `null`! Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: That sounds like a `<p:autoComplete>` specific quirk.

Comment: Hmm yes and the problem is that all fields refer to the same object, which means if no suggestion is selected for one field, the underlying value (draft.address) for all other fields will be null and their values will be ignored.

Comment: Just to be sure, is `Address#equals()` OK? (`other == this` covered) Otherwise use `omnifaces.ListIndexConverter`

Comment: When I use `omnifaces.ListIndexConverter`, enter a new street name but not select a value from the suggestions and submit the form it tries to convert the value from the textfield to an Integer: `int index = Integer.valueOf(value);` which yields: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Mainstreet"`

Comment: Perhaps I've to check it. Which PrimeFaces version?

Comment: PrimeFaces version 5.3

Comment: Is your bean view scoped?

Comment: Yes, it is view scoped but we are using our own view scope implementation

Comment: OK, as long as it's view scoped (i.e same instance during initial request, autocomplete, selection, save, etc).

Comment: Yes, that is the case

Comment: I indeed reproduced it. This appears to be a PF specific issue.

Comment: My workaround so far (before you answered me) was to write my own, address-specific `ListConverter`. Whenever the input wouldn't match one of the list member's `toString()` representation (because it was the actual value entered (which happened when not selecting a suggestion but entering a value manually) it would take the old value of the component (the `address` object) and invoke the respective setter with the value entered. It works but is very unstable since it relies on the reflection to work (textfield id's must be equal the model class' field names) and

Comment: I couldn't actually use `toString()` for comparison but had to use my own implementation since the invocation of the setter changed the `toString()` representation which would make it not to match successfully in a subsequent lookup.

Comment: The problem is, PF sends the plain input value instead of `itemValue="#{_address}"`, so the converter gets the plain input value instead of `Address#toString()`. This could be workarounded by extending the `ListConverter` and manipulating the `getAsString()` to return the street alone (you don't need to override `getAsObject()`!). The real solution is to report this issue to PF guys.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you could extend `ListConverter` for this specific case.

Comment: Okay I followed your advice don't really understand why but it works!!!  


I have twelve address fields though, so I will need to write twelve converters (or use reflection) and twelve tweaked autocomplete methods but that is okay I guess.